# Conditional ProxyPass Apache2

Tags: apache

I have two IP for Media Streaming
Ex:

- 1.1.1.1 [IP_ONE]
- 2.2.2.2 [IP_TWO]

I would like to check the file first on the IP_ONE using proxypass

> If `IP_ONE/file.txt` returns `404` go to `IP_TWO`

So far here is my Apache2 Conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName storage.domain.com

  SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/privkey.pem

  SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPass / http://1.1.1.1/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://1.1.1.1/
  ProxyPass / http://2.2.2.2/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://2.2.2.2/
</VirtualHost>
```

This Configuration works but it's giving me an Proxy Error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache proxy pass load balance module. You define a new loadBalancer specifiny which servers requests should be route to and then you configure the proxy pass to use the load balancer: more details can be found here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Comment: I tried this one. mod_proxy_balancer. But if the requested file is not found on one server it returns 404. Are there any fix for this?

Comment: Balancer just forward the requets. If it return 404, means the file is not there so you should be checking the server where the file should be.

Comment: can it be done with conditional statements to detect if 404?

Comment: That should be done on the backend server.